# WKWebview not detected as mobile

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView in my app. When I load a URL, it's not rendered for mobile. The same URL opened in Safari on the iPhone renders properly.

I tried registering the `customUserAgent` as `iphone` but unfortunately that did not do the trick.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

General, this website adaptive issue should be done by web developer. Go through `.css` file and write web layout in terms of percent

Comment: It doesn't answer his question: Why does the **same** HTML/CSS render differently on `WKWebView` and Mobile Safari.app?

Comment: Hey did it work ever? I had the same issue and don't know how to proceed